How can attached collision objects be recoloured in rviz2?
We are trying to change the colour of attached collision objects, so that different attached collision objects can have different colours at the same time.
In ros1 (Noetic), we were colouring attached collision objects via a three-step process:

Adding the collision object using moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface::applyCollisionObject. The object was then the colour specified in applyCollisionObject.
Attaching the collision object using moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::attachObject. The object was then the default attached collision object colour.
Recolouring the object by publishing a planning scene with object_colors. The object was then the colour specified in object_colours.

This doesn't work in ros2 (Humble). After attachObject, the object is the default attached collision object colour, and after publishing a planning scene with object_colors the object is white, regardless of the colour specified in object_colors.

Looks like this isn't currently possible in moveit2. See this PR for updates to making it available.
